# How to capture photo without user click (Phonegap)

Tags: android, cordova, capture, image, android-camera

I need to capture an image (all 2 minutes), but in an automatically way,
without requiring the user to click a button. It is possible?

Does a function exists to trigger an image capture?

Comment: In which mobile platform ?... Android or Blackberry or Windows or iPhone....?.. Add the required tags in the post

Comment: Ideally, I want this to work on Android and iPhone at least. But first of all, Android. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a feature of PhoneGap for the moment.